# IoT Foundation errors (The topic is not valid, The topic does not match an allowed rule)

Tags: mqtt, iot

I have a device connected to IBM IoT foundation. It uses a TI CC3100 Wi-Fi chip driven by an MSP430 MCU. The device used to connect perfectly to IOTF in the past. I didn't use it for a couple of months and now suddenly it does not connect. Did IBM recently change anything in the MQTT protocol for IOTF ?

I get the following messages on the device's console:

> Device is configured in default state
> Device started as STATION
> Connection established with AP
> Broker connect failed for conn no. 1
> Exiting the Application

In the Watson IoT foundation dashboard I see the following messages (in the connection log):

> Closed connection from 217.132.56.201. The topic does not match an allowed rule 2 times in the last 5 minutes   May 29, 2016 8:36:46 AM
> Closed connection from 217.132.56.201. The topic is not valid. 2 times in the last 5 minutes

Can anyone help resolving this problem ?

Thanks a lot,
Danny

Comment: Can you please provide more details so we can assist with troubleshooting?  What is your 6 character unique org ID?   What MQTT topic are you publishing on from the device?